# how to solve this scala installation problem

Tags: command-line, software-installation, java

hello I do if you asked me I typed javac 
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: I installed java scala 2.11.6 with 1.8
then m will appear Message error loading annotatedelement, class girl

Comment: Please put the error messages in your question because it is hard to read them in comments. Thanks.

Comment: Please I have published the error

Comment: Edit the question and write there how you installed java? Did you install just jre or jdk?   What is the output of `javac` in a terminal.

Comment: @lyly Please provide the information you got asked for, otherwise we can't analyse your problem and of course can't give you a solution.

Comment: for me to understand I am a compartaive study between hadoop is spark and i did not do it that installed java8 and hadoop me my spot only installed spark so I know how my teacher has installed java8 and I not master really I know what to do

Comment: Please if you can guide me to meet you

Comment: Sorry, but we can't help you if you don't answer our questions. If you don't know how to get a specific information, ask that. However, you have been simply asked for the output of `javac` - that means you open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T), type `javac`, hit ENTER, select the output text with your mouse, right-click on it, select "Copy" from the appearing context menu, click the [edit] link below your question, paste your command output at the end of it, select it again in the question editor ad press CTRL+K to format it properly.

Comment: And please try to improve your language a bit, sometimes it's quite hard to understand what you want to say... Translation services like https://translate.google.com might help you. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Are you looking for the solution? is the answer given works? if yes, try accepting answer. if no, edit question to say what didn't work. If  you're not looking for answers anymore, let us know that too

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, I can guess that you wanted to install oracle-java-8 and for any reason that installation wasn't successful or half-broken now. So, I suggest installing these to run scala-2.11.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.

1. First install java

   ```
   sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
   ```
2. Then install scala

   ```
   sudo apt install scala
   ```

The repository for Ubuntu 16.04 has scala verson 2.11.6 and I've installed it and tested without any problem.

If you face further problem, edit your question describing how the answer didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, install JDK

   sudo apt install default-jdk
2. Install [scala](https://www.coresumo.com/how-to-install-scala-on-ubuntu-linux-or-install-scala-on-mac-or-windows-10-or-setup-scala-3-0/)

   sudo apt-get install scala

   scala -version

Comment: Yes, almost the same answer, but here's `default-jdk` used instead of `openjdk-8-jdk` and it seems they are independent. I have both installed.